# Same serialversionUID for same installed Java versions

Tags: java, serialization

I have a simple question, which wasn't cleared properly by Googling:
If I install the same Java binary onto different computers, will their serialversionUID remain the same? If no, then other than explicitly changing, is their any mechanism wherein the serialversionUID's are different? Thanks for the explanation. 
(This is a link to the algorithm which generates the UID: [algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100))

Comment: Do you have the serialVersionUID declared in the source code or are you relying on the compiler to generate it?

Comment: @Dev  I was talking about Compiler Generated UID

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the serialVersionUIDs are just a member variables set to static values, and you didn't recompile the binaries between placing them on the first machine and the second.

It is the serialization / deserialization architecture which concerns itself with serialVersionUIDs, at run time.  If one modifies the source code of a class with a serialVersionUID, they are supposed to review the class for serialization compatibility with the unmodified version, and if incompatible, adjust the serialVerisonUID to an yet-unused value for that class.

Comment: If no explicit serialVersionUID is set, the JVM will generate one at runtime, not compiletime

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you make a good point.  However, for serialization to have any meaning (or functionality) the generation must yield like results for non-recompiled classes (unless Java gets wild one day and wants to break backwards compatibility).

Comment: That is true, but then you need to specify it yourself. As far as I know, the algorithm to calculate it if not explicitly set is JVM dependent (or at least it is not specified in the JLS or JVM spec), so it can be different between different JVM vendors.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I'd be shocked if the Java CTT doesn't effectively enforce a like algorithm.  In fact, project like this http://sab39.netreach.com/Software/Japitools/Usage/japicompat/60/ have explicit warnings if you don't use the "compatible" algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

"The stream-unique identifier is a 64-bit hash of the class name, interface class names, methods, and fields"
if you haven't changed the class code, it should be perfectly the same.

Comment: otherwise lot of functionality would fail, like serializing object in one machine and deserializing in other (like with JMS for exmaple)